# Is there a way to get an index of a node in DOM?

Tags: java, html, dom, offset

For exmaple, if I have a HTML document:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

`Hello` will be at index from 18 to 22 while `World` will be between 32 and 36.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The DOM and HTML are *not* the same thing.

The DOM is a tree structure which represents (Models) the content of the document. In a language like HTML, which is also tree-structured, the DOM closely resembles the structure of the source code, but it’s not quite the same.

A browser uses HTML to construct the DOM, but after that the HTML is unimportant. This is especially the case if you have weakly formed elements (such as `<p>` without the closing `</p>`) or start manipulating it with JavaScript.

It is possible to *reconstruct* the HTML from the DOM, but it won’t necessarily be the same. This is because you typically use white space (including line breaks) around HTML for readability. White space is either ignored if it’s in a non-text element or added to its own text node if it’s a mixed element.

Reconstruction is also non-identical if the original HTML includes mal-formed code.

Using the DOM and JavaScript, with some judicious CSS selectors, you can often work forwards, and find what you have. For example:

```
document.querySelector('html>body>p:nth-child(2)')
```

will get you that second paragraph in a modern browser, but DOM has no way of knowing where the data was in the original HTML.

If you don’t need to worry about the original HTML, foregoing the white spaces, line breaks and possible mal-formed code, then it may be possible to find what you’re looking for by re-constructing the HTML from the dom and just searching the string.

Otherwise, you will need to get at the original HTML as a string. If you really need, to know, you will need to fetch the page again as a text. You can do this using Ajax.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I am processing an HTML file in Java. But I assume it's still not possible with [Java DOM library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html)?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP Once the DOM has been constructed, the original source is lost. I have edited my answer with more detail. If you’re processing this in Java, does that mean that Java has access to the original HTML as a string?

Comment: Yes it could. But I am using HTML parser which would read the file as [`Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)

Comment: could you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868641/is-there-a-way-to-extract-text-verbatim-in-between-html-tags-in-dom) as well?

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP Sorry, I’ve had a quick look at the API (I’m not actually a Java Developer, so I have no real experience with the Java DOM Library), and I think you’re up against the same problem. By the time you have the DOM, the original content is lost. I will repeat this comment on the other question.