# Is there a way to extract text verbatim in between HTML tags in DOM?

Tags: java, html, dom

For example, for an HTML document:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>Hello <b>world</b></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can use `getTextContent()` to get `"Hello world"`, but is there a way to get `"Hello <b>world</b>"`?

Comment: Sorry, I’ve had a quick look at the API (I’m not actually a Java Developer, so I have no real experience with the Java DOM Library), and I think you’re up against the same problem. By the time you have the DOM, the original content is lost.

Comment: I your example, you have omitted the spaces around __Hello__. Is that part of the plan?

Comment: No, let me edit the text

Comment: This question probably has an answer here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can apply a XSLT transformation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html

What you need is to retrieve the XML content of the element subtree. There are several questions in SO addressing this issue:
[How to I output org.w3c.dom.Element to string format in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java)

[Java/DOM: Get the XML content of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484995/java-dom-get-the-xml-content-of-a-node)

[Get a node's inner XML as String in Java DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300839/get-a-nodes-inner-xml-as-string-in-java-dom)